# TypeError: "name" is read-only

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to implement the prototype pattern in a Sharepoint Framework small example, I took the sample from here:

https://mertarauh.com/tutorials/typescript-design-patterns/prototype-pattern/

and adapted as below:

```
 class Employee  {

    private totalperMonth: number;


    constructor(public name: string, public hiredDate: Date, public dailyRate: number){
        this.totalperMonth = dailyRate * 20 ;
    }

    public display(): string{
        return "Employee " + this.name + " earns per month: " + this.totalperMonth;
    }

    public clone():Employee{
        var cloned = Object.create(Employee || null);
        Object.keys(this).map((key: string) => {
            cloned[key]= this[key];
        });
        return <Employee>cloned;
    }
}

export default Employee;
```

and the component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './Prototype.module.scss';
import { IPrototypeProps } from './IPrototypeProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import  Employee from './Employee';


export default class Prototype extends React.Component<IPrototypeProps, {}> {


  public render(): React.ReactElement<IPrototypeProps> {
    const today = new Date();
    let employee1: Employee = new Employee('Luis', today, 500);
    let employee2 = employee1.clone();
    employee2.dailyRate = 550;

    return (
      <div className={ styles.prototype }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
              <span className={ styles.title }>Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
              <p className={ styles.subTitle }>Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
              <p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>
                <span className={ styles.label }>{employee1.display()}</span>
                <span className={ styles.label }>{employee2.display()}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However I get in the console this error:

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I'm not used to the sharepoint framework but I had some troubles dealing with immutability while testing with Jest. In my case, using Object.defineProperty allowed me to workaround the problem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: did you defined name variable anywhere ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with this approach.

Classes are first-class citizens in TypeScript, alternative approaches to inheritance can make type safety much less straightforward.

`Object.create` is low-level tool, it isn't a good idea to use it unless you know what you're doing and why. The actual mistake here is that wrong prototype was chosen (`Employee` instead of `Employee.prototype`), so `name` property refers to [function `name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), which is read-only and shouldn't be reassigned. A proper way to implement `clone` would be:

```
public clone():Employee{
    return Object.assign(Object.create(Employee.prototype), this);
}
```

The fact that it ignores class constructor is a doubtful decision because a constructor may contain logic that differs from one applied in `clone`.

React promotes functional programming as a substitute to OOP, it's beneficial to maintain application state as plain objects rather than class instances, this may help to avoid design flaws that will be costly to fix in future. There's nothing that would really require a class in this case. The same thing could be expressed as:

```
const createEmployee = (name, hiredDate, dailyRate) => ({
 name,
 hiredDate,
 dailyRate,
 totalperMonth: dailyRate * 20
});

...

let employee1 = createEmployee('Luis', today, 500);
let employee2 = {...employee1, dailyRate: 550};
```

Notice that `totalperMonth` isn't recalculated neither in `Employee` class nor in `createEmployee` factory function. This may be undesirable (see the note on a constructor above).

Comment: I am just trying to implement the prototype pattern in a simple react component, I already solved the name readonly error, by declaring the properties explicitly and not in the constructor, but still got this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54161690/display-is-not-a-function?noredirect=1#comment95153278_54161690

Comment: I wouldn't say that this pattern is beneficial in React, so it may be antipattern. Any way, the answer already explains what was wrong. You used wrong prototype. The answer in the question you linked is also incorrect. `Object.getPrototypeOf(Employee) === Function.prototype`. That's wrong prototype, too. A correct proto is `Employee.prototype`. Notice that `totalperMonth` won't be recalculated. Is this expected behaviour?