# display is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an employee class with a display function, and then when trying to implement the prototype pattern, I got an error when trying to use the display function from the cloned object.

[image]

The employee class code:

class Employee  {

```
    private totalperMonth: number;
    private name: string;
    private hiredDate: Date;
    public dailyRate: number;


    constructor(name: string, hiredDate: Date, dailyRate: number){
        this.totalperMonth = dailyRate * 20 ;
    }

    public display(): string{
        return "Employee " + this.name + " earns per month: " + this.totalperMonth;
    }

    public clone():Employee{
        var cloned = Object.create(Employee || null);
        Object.keys(this).map((key: string) => {
            cloned[key]= this[key];
        });
        return <Employee>cloned;
    }
}

export default Employee;
```

the component code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './Prototype.module.scss';
import { IPrototypeProps } from './IPrototypeProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import  Employee from './Employee';


export default class Prototype extends React.Component<IPrototypeProps, {}> {


  public render(): React.ReactElement<IPrototypeProps> {
    const today = new Date();
    let employee1: Employee = new Employee('Luis', today, 500);
    let employee2 = employee1.clone();
    employee2.dailyRate = 550;

    return (
      <div className={ styles.prototype }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
              <span className={ styles.title }>Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
              <p className={ styles.subTitle }>Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
              <p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>
                <span className={ styles.label }>{employee1.display()}</span>
                <span className={ styles.label }>{employee2.display()}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `<Employee>cloned` doesn't actually make the object an instance of `Employee`, you need to be doing `new Employee(...)` somewhere.

Comment: I took the sample from here and adapted: https://mertarauh.com/tutorials/typescript-design-patterns/prototype-pattern/

Comment: the goal of the prototype pattern is to avoid instantiating new objects and instead clone them

Comment: If that's what you're copying, note that you've missed the `prototype` property access...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    clone():Employee {
        return Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(Employee)), this)
    }
```

This creates a new object based on the current object class, whilst also filling up the data with the ones that you previously had.

Your solution didn't actually make it an Employee, as it was just a cloned plain object.

Comment: I get this error with your code: Property 'assign' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959372/property-assign-does-not-exist-on-type-objectconstructor